# AutoFac equivalent code in Unity

Tags: refactoring, unity-container, autofac

We are tasked to refactor an app built using AutoFac and use Unity. We have managed to migrate most of the code, however struggling with one piece, would appreciate if could get an equivalent of the following snippet in Unity

```
   var consumers = typeFinder.FindClassesOfType(typeof(IConsumer<>)).ToList();
        foreach (var consumer in consumers)
        {
            builder.RegisterType(consumer)
                .As(consumer.FindInterfaces((type, criteria) =>
                {
                    var isMatch = type.IsGenericType && ((Type)criteria).IsAssignableFrom(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
                    return isMatch;
                }, typeof(IConsumer<>)))
                .InstancePerHttpRequest();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you are after:

```
var openConsumerType = typeof(IConsumer<>);
var consumers = typeFinder.FindClassesOfType(openConsumerType).ToList();
container.RegisterTypes(consumers,
    t => t.GetInterfaces()
        .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && 
            openConsumerType.IsAssignableFrom(i.GetGenericTypeDefinition())),
     getLifetimeManager: t => new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Hopefully my understanding of the `FindInterfaces` method is close enough.

The `PerRequestLifetimeManager` should be equivalent to `.InstancePerHttpRequest()`